# Is Visual Studio Code v.1.66 available on Rasberry Pi OS?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use Visual Studio Code on Rasberry Pi. I tried to sync data today and received an error asking me to upgrade to VSC v.1.66 (currently on v.1.65). I can't see that a v.1.66 is available for Rasberry Pi, package manager suggests that v.1.65 is the current version and VSC itself confirms the same... am I missing something?

Cheers,

Dave

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as you and I have not yet found version 1.66 for my raspberry pi4.

But I have an alternative solution and here is how it works.

You can use vs code an ssh.

Here is a link to a video that shows how to do it.

https://youtu.be/jvi1nmKK81Y

While waiting for version 1.66, this solution is very practical.

Also, I tested "git push origin master" and it works fine.

I hope my solution will help you.

Comment: Could you quote the solution incase the video gets taken down then the answer is documented.